# Mandrill's UNSUB merge tag not getting parsed

Tags: api, mandrill

I'm trying to make it so when someone clicks on the unsubscribe link in an email sent via the Mandrill API (using PHP) it works as described in: http://help.mandrill.com/entries/23815367-Can-I-add-an-automatic-unsubscribe-link-to-Mandrill-emails-

The `*|UNSUB|*` merge tag is not getting parsed. It just comes through in the the body of the email received.

Near the end of the message content ($message_content) I have:

```
<a href="*|UNSUB:http:/mydomain.com/unsubscribe-from-mailing-lists/|*">Click here to unsubscribe.</a>
```

In Gmail, the link is: Click here to unsubscribe.
(NOT a valid HREF, so Gmail just ignores the anchor tag)

In Outlook 2010 the link is: Click here to unsubscribe.
(Not a valid HREF)

Is there some merge_vars parameter I should add to the headers?
http://help.mandrill.com/entries/21678522-How-do-I-use-merge-tags-to-add-dynamic-content- mentions them, but I can't find what the parameter should be for the UNSUB merge tag.

```
$mandrill = new Mandrill($mandrill_api_key);
        $message = array(
            'html' => $message_content,
            'subject' => $subject,
            'from_email' => 'me@mydomain.com',
            'from_name' => 'MY NAME',
            'to' => $to_list,       
            'headers' => array('Reply-To' => 'me@mydomain.com'),
            'important' => false,
            'track_opens' => 1,
            'track_clicks' => null,
            'auto_text' => null,
            'auto_html' => null,
            'inline_css' => null,
            'url_strip_qs' => null,
            'preserve_recipients' => 0,
            'view_content_link' => 1,
            'tracking_domain' => null,
            'signing_domain' => null,
            'return_path_domain' => null,
            'merge' => true,
            'global_merge_vars' => array(
                array(
                    'unsub' => 'unsub'
                )
            ),

        );
```

What step am I missing?
TIA!

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the URL was missing a slash (http:/mydomain...)
This was caused by TinyMCE converting URLs. I added `convert_urls: false` to the tinymce.init and that solved my problem.

Kudos to Mandrill Support for helping me identify the problem.

Comment: Hi! can you please share some more details, like where is this .init file located? and is it doing fine with latest update of WP 3.9. I am facing the same problem, but couldn't find where to change this property.